# Calling Me(index) in a class inherited from List, having a custom indexer not working as expected

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, inheritance

I've recently converted a `C#` code to `VB.NET`, it's a custom control called `CheckBoxComboBox`.

One of the classes I converted inherits from `List`. It also has an indexer such as:

```
Public Class CheckBoxComboBoxItemList
    Inherits List(Of CheckBoxComboBoxItem)

    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal displayName As String) As CheckBoxComboBoxItem
        Get
            Dim StartIndex As Integer = If(_CheckBoxComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList AndAlso _CheckBoxComboBox.DataSource Is Nothing, 1, 0)
            For Index As Integer = StartIndex To Count - 1 Step 1
                Dim oItem As CheckBoxComboBoxItem = Me(Index)
                Dim Text As String
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(oItem.Text) AndAlso oItem.DataBindings IsNot Nothing AndAlso oItem.DataBindings("Text") IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim PropertyInfo As PropertyInfo = oItem.ComboBoxItem.[GetType]().GetProperty(oItem.DataBindings("Text").BindingMemberInfo.BindingMember)
                    Text = CStr(PropertyInfo.GetValue(oItem.ComboBoxItem, Nothing))
                Else
                    Text = oItem.Text
                End If

                If Text.CompareTo(displayName) = 0 Then Return oItem
            Next

            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(String.Format("""{0}"" does not exist in this combo box.", displayName))
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Whenever I call any instance of this class with a given index, such as:

```
Dim NewList As CheckBoxComboBoxItemList = New CheckBoxComboBoxItemList()
'Let's consider the above list is already populated.
Dim _CheckBoxComboBoxItem as CheckBoxComboBoxItem = NewList(1)
```

I am getting the following:

> System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'

I know why this is happening, however I can't understand it.
In the above indexer that I showed, I am calling:

```
Dim oItem As CheckBoxComboBoxItem = Me(Index)
```

Where `Index` is an integer, but the indexer being called is the one with a string parameter, so it's creating an endless recursive calls.

I tried to overload the indexer with another one using:

```
Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As CheckBoxComboBoxItem
    Get
        Return MyBase.Item(index) 
    End Get
End Property
```

And that fixed the problem. But I still have this question:

Shouldn't `Me(Index)` use the base class `List` indexer when `Index` is an integer? Why does it use the indexer I wrote when clearly the parameter is an Integer and not a String? Note that in the `C#` code, this error didn't happen.

Comment: What is the setting of Option Explicit in your project configuration?

Comment: Welcome to Visual Basic..

Comment: @Steve Option Explicit is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your declaration in the derived class hides or `Shadows` the routine in the base class, rather than overloading it.  See the help topic "Shadowing in Visual Basic" for more details.  The VB compiler will usually warn about omission of the `Shadows` keyword in situations where shadowing occurs.

If you want to maintain the shadowing behavior, but call to the base class indexer, you can use the `MyBase` keyword.

```
Dim oItem As CheckBoxComboBoxItem = MyBase.Item(Index)
```

Alternatively, you can add the `Overloads` keyword to the declaration of your derived class routine, which will signal to VB that you do not want to hide the base class declaration.

```
Default Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal displayName As String) As CheckBoxComboBoxItem
```

Comment: Yes, I did have the warning about Shadowing. My first problem was that I tried to `Override` instead of `Overloads`. Both the method I showed in my question and `Overloads` fixes the error. My question is more about what's going on in the underlying layers? Why do I have to explicitly tell the compiler that this method has to Overload the base one (Which I guess happens in C#)

Comment: @PaulKaram If I had to speculate, the reason for the difference is that overloads are explicit in VB vs. implicit in C#.  Therefore, hiding will only occur explicitly in C# (with the `new` keyword), whereas overloading will only occur explicitly in VB.  In most cases, this is an area where VB is actually a bit more user-friendly than C# (which otherwise tends to make everything with potential ambiguity explicit), but this is a place where the VB design is potentially confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload it. You would've had an error if you had Option Strict On.

```
Default Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal displayName As String) As CheckBoxComboBoxItem
```